# How to extract a number from an image using OCR with Tesseract.js?

Tags: javascript

How can I extract a number from an image using Javascript with OCR with Tesseract.js, then add the number together.

I could extract the number in words using this code but I do not know how to convert them to array and then sum the four numbers together. let say the number image that I want to scan on my phone is 4567.

If I change the text to number from console.log it doesn't show the number 4567

```js
var myImage = document.getElementById('userImage');

Tesseract.recognize(myImage).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.text);
})
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
<img id="userImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=4567" />
```

Comment: Have you tried - `console.log(parseInt(result.text));`

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Tesseract does not trust the placeholder image

Answer (score 3):

Just created a sample or a simple implementation, not the best code but obviously you can refer this https://github.com/Mondal10/image-scanner

Answer (score 0):

```js
function startProcessing() {
  let img = document.getElementById('ocr');
  Tesseract.recognize(
    img,
    'eng', {
      logger: m => console.log(m)
    }
  ).then((res) => res).then(({
    data
  }) => {
    console.log(data.text, typeof(data.text)); // returns type as string
    console.log(Number(data.text), parseInt(data.text)); // converting string to number

    // Array with number i.e '4567' --> [4,5,6,7]
    let convertedNumber = [...data.text].map((num) => Number(num));
    // Calculating the sum of the numbers in convertedNumber Array
    let sum = convertedNumber.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
    console.log(':::SUM:::', sum);
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.0.0-beta.1/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="ocr" onload="startProcessing()" width="500px" height="300px" src="./ocr1.png" alt="random">
  <!-- image downloaded from link http://podam.org/ocr/ocr.html -->
  <!-- Make sure you download the image and save it locally if you try to fetch it from url you will get CORS error -->
</body>

</html>
```

> `<img id="userImage" src="ocr.png"/>`
>   var myImage= document.getElementById('userImage'); Tesseract.recognize(myImage).then(function(result){ console.log(result.text); alert(result.text); })

*Note: This solution works provided we scan only numbers, if it is combination of both then some more conditions might require to handle string + number situations, Also make sure image is clear enough with porper contrast*

Comment: thanks very much, but the thing was showing " TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value" pls. you can check the url http://podam.org/ocr/ocr.html. I will like it if you can be more explicit on the use of function reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr). basically what I want this javascript to do is to for my mobile phone to scan the number when pressing the scan button and to add all the four numbers together.;

Comment: You can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce for more insight on reduce.
And for the error: `TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value`, Thats causing because the `convertedNumber` array is empty

Comment: Amit Mondal,  thanks for your help. I want to ask why the converted numbers from my image does not stored automatically as an array using this code you gave me up above let convertedNumber = [...result.text].map((num) => Number(num)); when I added the array manually like this convertedNumber = [4, 5, 6, 7]; it works.

Comment: Is `result.text` returning a string of the scanned image?

Comment: let convertedNumber = [...result.text].map((num) => Number(num)); does not return any string of scanned image.

Comment: No just `console.log(result.text)` before this line
`let convertedNumber = [...result.text].map((num) => Number(num));`
and `console.log(convertedNumber)` after

Comment: pls. can you help me re-write this code the way it supposed to be. I'm really getting frustrated

Comment: Updated the code please refer it, place everything in the root of folder. Tested it works fine with my code